# in many-to-many relationships, can you delete a row from one table without deleting any rows from the second table?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, crud, fastapi

I am creating a database & working on CRUD functions. I've run into a problem with the **Delete** functionality.

I have two tables, connected in a many-to-many relationship via an association table. I want to delete a row from only *one* of the tables. And presumably I will also have to remove the rows in the association table mentioning this row. But I don't want to delete anything from the other table.

For example, using one of the examples of many-to-many I've seen, (Students & Classes):

1. There is a table of students, **Students**. There is a table of classes, **Classes**. Each student is linked to multiple classes. Each class is linked to multiple students.
2. The **Students** and **Classes** tables are linked via an association table **StudentsvsClasses**.
3. Suppose one student drops out of university. I want to drop this student from **Students**, and links to all their classes (listed in **StudentsvsClasses**). However, I don't want to delete any rows in **Classes**. Because these classes still exist, and are associated with other students.

How can I implement this? Is it even possible? I'm new to this and am unable to find an example. Most examples I have found (**Parents** & **Children** examples) involve: deleting a parent from the **Parent** table, and also deleting all associated children from the **Children** table.

If anyone can point me to an example of this online, or can help out, it would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if my wording was unclear, or if I can clarify anything. I'd appreciate any and all help with this. Thanks!

Here's the code of my toy example – the models.py file:

```py
StudentsvsClasses = Table('StudentsvsClasses',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('student_key', String, ForeignKey('students.student_id')),
    Column('class_key', String, ForeignKey('classes.class_id'))  
)           

class Students(Base):
    __tablename__ = "students"
    student_id = Column(String, unique=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    student_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    associated_classes = relationship(
        "Classes",
        secondary=StudentsvsClasses,
        back_populates="associated_students"
)

class Classes(Base):
    __tablename__ = "classes"
    class_id = Column(String, unique=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    class_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    associated_students = relationship(
        "Students",
        secondary=StudentsvsClasses,
        back_populates="associated_classes"
    )
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#using-delete-cascade-with-many-to-many-relationships)?

Comment: @GordThompson Hi! Thanks for commenting. Yes, I have read the documentation; and looked at several other tutorials as well. From what I understand, what I'm looking for should be the default behavior, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I've tried different permutations and combinations of cascade options as well, but it doesn't help. Do you have any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/MCapKq4R) works for me.